# SegFault on fprintf

Tags: c++, c, segmentation-fault, printf, fopen

I do not know why the program runs into a segfault after my printf on the first fprintf. Do anybody has an idea? The directories are working and the txt file gets created.

```
    void visualisierung(int M,int L, float p,float q,float r,int n,
int step,int stepm, char dateiname3[]){
            FILE *fp,*fp2;
            zelle **liste,*listehilf;
            int i,j,anz,teilchenmax,teilchenneu,nt,me;
            time_t zeit;
            double multiplier,dichte;
            double fluss[101];
            char dateiname[100],dateiname2[100];
            zeit=time(NULL);
            //erstellen eines neuen Ordners
            mkdir("currentvids",0755);
            chdir("currentvids");
            strcpy(dateiname,dateiname3);
            strcpy(dateiname2,dateiname3);
            strcat(dateiname2,".txt");
            mkdir(dateiname,0755);
            chdir(dateiname);
            fp=fopen(dateiname2,"w");
                printf("No SegFault yet\n");

                fprintf(fp, "#Matrix %ix%i\n", M,L);
                fprintf(fp, "#Particle Size: %ix%i\n", n,n);
                fprintf(fp, "#p: %f\n", p);
                fprintf(fp, "#q: %f\n", q);
                fprintf(fp, "#v: %f\n", 1-(p+q+r));
                fprintf(fp, "#steps before measurement: %i\n", step);
                fprintf(fp, "#number of measured steps: %i\n", stepm);
```

Comment: TL;DR; Mismatching format specifiers and variable types somewhere perhaps?

Comment: My guess would be, `fopen` failed and `fp` is `NULL`.

Comment: Check the return value of `fopen()`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik _"The directories are working and the txt file gets created."_

Comment: maybe change the first fprintf to printf without fp and tell us which line is going to crash then?

Comment: Which language - C or C++?

Comment: _@Gerard_ In general you should inspect your progam with the debugger line by line first to identify the exact source of the exception.

Comment: any chance to rise ulimit on core file creation and inspecting core file with gdb?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't receiving a `dateiname3` longer than `dateiname2` (=100 chars) can handle? (... `strcpy/strcat` ... shudders )

Comment: hey, thx for your comments! the file gets created empty, the segfault must be thrown after my printf. the language is c++ (for some random generators), but as you can see I'm programing mostly in c

Comment: @GerardJúlio As mentioned step through with the debugger to identify the exact source of the segfault.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ oh dear, I'm compiling my code with gcc, I'm not into into the deep stuff of debugging, but I know, that the first fopen throws the fault and that the pointer isn't null

Comment: @GerardJúlio _"that the first fopen throws the fault and that the pointer isn't null"_  That is contradictorily.. Learn how to use the debugger, this is an essential skill for every serious programmer.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ sorry, I meant the first fprintf(), fopen() doesn't makes any sense here

Comment: @GerardJúlio Though that doesn't mean the segfault occurs at your 1st `fprintf()`, that the file is empty isn't a proof. Files are written buffered, unless you apply a `flush()` after each `fprintf()`. Again: Use the debugger, with any modern IDE it's fairly easy to use it.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ you're right, I tried to change the first fprintf in printf though, printf is working, the next fprintf throws the fault. The pointer has to be broken!

Comment: @GerardJúlio What's the value of the pointer? Is it `NULL`?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ nope, 938e008 for example

Comment: @GerardJúlio Sounds much like you have some undefined behavior/stack corruption then.

Comment: Consider pasting your code into an online c++ compiler such as ideone.com or cpp.sh and getting it to compile without errors while still reproducing the crash. If you really think it is this particular function, it should be easy to make it compile online (although for online I would replace all fprintf by printf).

Comment: @V-R printf is no problem, it is this function indeed

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) indent after every opening brace '{'.  un-indent before every closing brace '}'. (suggest using 4 spaces for each indent level, NEVER use tabs for indenting as every word processor/editor has the tab stops/tab width set to individual preferences.  2) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.  3) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, default, case) via a blank line.

Comment: When asking a question about a run time problem, post code that cleanly compiles, is reasonably short, and still shows the problem.  the posted code is not even a complete function, so it does not compile.  Please repost a complete program, short, that exhibits the problem.